# Line break, new line in KDoc

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, kdoc

Assuming we have such documented string

```
/** retrieve a state of the service
* <br/> HTTP code 200 - normal state
* <br/> HTTP code 403 - some recoverable state:
const val SERVICE_STATE = "servicestate" */
```

There are several **`<br/>`** here, which i used to break a line, like i do in java, but output of *AndroidStudio* (seems same in *InteliJIdea*) is 
[image]

with java it is parsed & displayed correctly:

```
/** retrieve a state of the service
 * <br/> HTTP code 200 - normal state
 * <br/> HTTP code 403 - some recoverable state */
public static final String SERVICE_STATE = "servicestate";
```

[image]

Can i somehow achieve the same with kotlin & IntelijIdea, maybe kotlin has another option to break the line in KDoc?

Comment: If someone is looking for this, please vote on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-6702!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The KDoc format [uses Markdown syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#inline-markup) instead of HTML, and basic Markdown does not provide a way to break the line without starting a new paragraph.

<sup>I'm not sure why the [Kotlin IntellIJ plugin does not support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-6702/KDoc-Dokka-allow-for-newlines-line-breaks-inside-paragraphs) `<br/>` or the [double space hack](https://gist.github.com/shaunlebron/746476e6e7a4d698b373).</sup>

If starting a new paragraph is OK, just skip an empty line:

```
/** 
 * retrieve a state of the service
 *
 * HTTP code 200 - normal state
 *
 * HTTP code 403 - some recoverable state:
 */
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: (updated the answer – removed the redundant `<br/>` tags)

Comment: It seems that KDoc doesn't takes the line in the new paragraph.

Comment: What about leaving an empty line between two code lines? I couldn't find it.

Comment: The double-space is not a hack, it's a feature described in the [documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p).

Answer (score 12):

To add to [@hotkey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559184/6346531), you can also use triple backticks as Markdown is supported:

````kotlin
/**
 * Returns masked complement, i.e. expected value in the [maskBits] bits instead of a negative number because of
 * 2's complement representation
 *
 * For example, for 9:
 * ```
 *  Binary representation:         00...01001
 *  Complement:                    11...10110 which is -10
 *  Masking with 4 bits:  and with 00...01111
 *  So we get:                     00...00110 which is the expected bitwise complement
 * ```
 * @param maskBits Number of bits to mask the complement to
 * @return Decimal representation of the masked complement
 */
fun Int.inv(maskBits: Int) = inv() and 2.pow(maskBits) - 1
````

The result is:

[image]

Comment: plus one for backticks

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use dashes in lists. Empty lines are not needed in this case.

[image]

Comment: And the dashes can be nested too!  Very nice.